# Поиск, двойной интервал в MySQL

Tags: поиск, mysql

Есть таблица

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sq_min` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sq_max` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Дамп данных таблицы `test`
--

INSERT INTO `test` (`id`, `sq_min`, `sq_max`) VALUES
(1, 50, 200),
(2, 45, 49),
(3, 210, 250),
(4, 45, 55),
(5, 195, 205);
```

Как сделать поиск по этой таблице. Если в поиске тоже задается минимум и максимум.

Comment: А что нужно найти? Все интервалы, которые попадают в заданный? Или все интервалы, которые содержат заданный? Или?..

Comment: получается строчка это лот. 
нужно найти все лоты например которые входят в интервал
в лоте например sq_min = 50 и  sq_max=200
в форме поиска ввели
от 10 до 49
от 100 до 150
от 10 до 60
от 150 до 250
как составить запрос чтоб оно находило по всем кроме первого условия данный лот

Comment: Для каждого интервала один запрос, или в одном запросе отобрать записи, подходящие для хотя бы одного интервала из формы ? Уточните свой вопрос, а то непонятно.

Comment: Да, для каждого интервала свой запрос. Поиск от 10 до 49 или поиск от 100 до 150 и т.д.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM `table` 
WHERE 
   (sq_min > $sq_min AND sq_min < $sq_max) 
AND 
   (sq_max < $sq_max AND sq_max > $sq_min)
```

или

```
SELECT * FROM `table` 
WHERE 
   (sq_min > $sq_min AND sq_min < $sq_max) 
OR
   (sq_max < $sq_max AND sq_max > $sq_min)
```

Не разобрать ваш текст. Знаки препинания ставьте, хотябы.
Судя по вашему примеру подходит второй вариант.

```
SELECT * FROM `table` 
WHERE 
   sq_min > $sq_min 
AND 
   sq_max < $sq_max 
AND 
   type=$type
```

$sq_min, $sq_max - передается из формы.

Comment: супер. работает как я хотел!

Comment: @Ёхарный Бабай
А не проще **`... WHERE (sq_min < $sq_max) AND (sq_max > $sq_min)`**? Это если исходить из того, что обе пары возрастающие и ищем !!(пересечение).

ЗЫ: При таких условиях ваше так и сокращается, ок, тогда я предложил оптимизацию)

Comment: И то верно)))))

Comment: а как быть если еще условия в запросе. например type=1. Правильно я понял: 
WHERE ((sq_min > $sq_min AND sq_min < $sq_max)OR(sq_max < $sq_max AND sq_max > $sq_min)) and type=1

Comment: в комментариях обрезает перенос строки. WHERE (sq_min < $sq_max) AND (sq_max > $sq_min) - вариант не работает. если искать меньше нижнего предела..например у лота нижний придел 100 , а мы делаем выборку от 90. не пойму как добавить к запросу  (sq_min > $sq_min AND sq_min < $sq_max) 
OR
   (sq_max < $sq_max AND sq_max > $sq_min) еще штук 10 параметров?

Answer (score -1):

10 до 49 от 100 до 150 от 10 до 60 от 150 до 250 
если для каждого интервала один запрос получается 4 SQL селекта в цикле Тормозить будет. 
Если оперативка позволяет думаю лучше сделать один запрос с самого самого наименьшего 10 до наибольшего 250
Потом программно с помощью Linq или по старинке рассортировать.